# Unusual (to me) Phrasing of Power Analysis Objective; Interpretation Requested

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistical-power

I am reading a field biology manual that is directing me to do a power analysis, and I find the phrasing very confusing. It says:

*Determine sampling requirement to be 80% confident you are within 10% of the objective. (More concretely: how many survey plots do I need to be 80% confident of whether I am within 10% of having 65 trees per hectare?)*

It's phrased like a power analysis, but is confidence a synonym for power, and is being with 10% an indication of the alpha?

*Can anyone suggest what the statement means mathematically (e.g., B = 0.8)?
*Can anyone recommend an R package for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find out how many survey plots are needed to make the confidence interval (CI) equals 56.5 ~ 71.5 with the confidence level (CL) equals 80%. In other words, how many survey plots are needed in order to be able to claim with 80% confidence that there are 56.5~71.5 trees per hectare on average.

Comment: I doubt this is correct, because no amount of sampling could assure the CI will be $[56.5,71.5]$ unless the true mean really is $65.$

Comment: Thanks for that point whuber. What if I did indeed switch the question around to: "how many plots do I need to be 80% confident I am within 10% of the true mean?", regardless of if the true mean is 65 or not. In that case, does the 80% refer to power and the 10% to alpha/significance?

Comment: The number (denoted as n1) of samples used to obtain  the mean (of the number of trees per hectare, i.e. 65 in this case)  and the number (denoted as n2) of samples needed to obtain the specified CI with a specified CL are two different things. Here you are asked to find out n2 which is unknown. This does not necessarily mean "n1 is unknown". A possible situation is that the mean of 65 has been obtained based on n1 samples, and now ask you what is the value of n2 needed to achieve the required CI with specified CL.